# Python script error :Unable to read csv file

Tags: python, subprocess

Im Trying to Process below tab csv file line by line .It raising error.Unable to trace where im  wrong.

Here is the file :

/tmp/fa.csv

```
1       Close
6       Close
72      Close
99      Close
8       Close
4       Close
3       Close
103     Close
106     Close
107     Close
105     Close
220     Open
```

9.py

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/fa.csv') as f:
rown = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
for row in rown:
print row[1]
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# python 9.py
  File "9.py", line 3
    rown = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Check your indentation... Python I far less permissive than C on indent !

Comment: provide and indentation before `print` statement as the error says

Comment: The error message literally tells you where the error is and what it is, and infers what you need to do :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndentationError` error. Push the content inside the `with` statement

**Ex:**

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/fa.csv') as f:
    rown = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in rown:
        print row[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The Error you're getting is `indentation` error, not exactly of your logic in the code.

Here is complete working code:-

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/fa.csv') as f:
    rown = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in rown:
        print row
```